# Instantiating a new object - error

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle{
protected:
    string type;
    int wheels;
    bool engine; // number of engines in vehicle

public:
   Vehicle(string t, int w,bool e):
        type(t), wheels(w), engine(e){};
    void setType(string t) {type = t;}
    void setWheels(int w) {wheels = w;}
    void setEngine(int e) {engine = e;} // number of engines, 0 - False.
    string getType(){return type;}
    int getWheels() {return wheels;}
    bool getEngine() {cout << "1 - Has Engine | 0 - No Engine"; return engine;}


};

class Auto:public Vehicle {
private:
    string brand;
    int year;
public:
    Auto(string t, int w, bool e, string b, int y):
        Vehicle(t,w,e), brand(b),year(y) {};

    void setBrand(string b) {brand = b;}
    void setYear(int y) {year = y;}
    string getBrand() {return brand;}
    int getYear() {return year;}
};

int main()
{
    // This first segment of the program demonstrates the relationship
   // between the base class and derived class through the use of
  // a constructor.
Auto Spider360("Car",4,2,"Ferrari",2000);
cout << "Car type: " << Spider360.getType() << endl;
cout << "Number of wheels: " << Spider360.getWheels() << endl;
cout << " Has Engine: " << Spider360.getEngine() << "\n";
cout << "Brand: " << Spider360.getBrand() << endl;
cout << "Year: " << Spider360.getYear() << "\n\n";

// Now I use member functions directly to assign values to an object

Auto SuperAmerica;

return 0;

}
```

I am unable to declare the object Auto SuperAmerica; I get the following error: "No matching function call for Auto::Auto()" and for SuperAmerica, i do not want to use a constructor to set the values, I want to use my Set functions.

Comment: Then you'll need a default constructor.

Comment: @chris Thank you, So I need a default constructor in both the Vehicle and Auto classes ?

Comment: Yes, unless you're planning on initializing the latter with default values.

Answer (score 0):

The error of

```
"No matching function call for Auto::Auto()"
```

means that you cannot instantiate the class in the way you wanted. If you want to create the object and then initialize its members later, using setters, then use a [default constructor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr376.htm).